# how do I stop npm adding ^ to saved packages by default

Tags: node.js, npm

Therefore instead of:

```
"jquery": "^3.1.1",
```

I'd have:

```
"jquery": "3.1.1",
```

by running:

```
npm install jquery --save
```

**I'd be grateful if someone can tell me:** What is the benefit of using the '^'? In my experience it's caused a lot of headache when certain one package update causes other packages or the rest of the code to stop working. I can't see what benefit using the later-than-version character brings.

Answer (score 2):

To specify by default a exact version, you can change your npm config with [save-exact](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/config#save-exact):

```
npm config set save-exact true
```

If you only want to do this for a specific package, you can add --save-exact to the command line. E.g

```
npm install --save --save-exact jquery@3.1.1.
```